# WordPress Multisite Domain Mapping Issue: Subsite Domain Redirecting to Primary Domain

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I'm encountering challenges with domain mapping in a WordPress multisite environment. My subsite domain, set up as an alias in Plesk to the primary domain, either redirects to the primary domain or to the Plesk login page. I've tried various configurations and followed multiple guides, but the issue persists. Here are the specifics of my setup and the problem:

**Plesk Configuration:**

- The subsite (subsite.com) is configured in Plesk as an alias domain
  to the primary domain (primarydomain.com).
- Both domains share the same document root: /httpdocs/.
- SSL certificates are valid and active for both domains.
- DNS settings for subsite.com point to the same server as
  primarydomain.com.

**WordPress Multisite Settings:**

- In the WordPress Multisite Network Admin, I updated the site URL for the subsite to be https://subsite.com/ (not actual domain).

**Current Issues:**

- Accessing subsite.com results in a redirect to primarydomain.com.

I'm looking for guidance on resolving these redirection issues in a WordPress multisite with domain aliasing in Plesk. Any insights or suggestions on how to properly configure this setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you say domain mapping can you be specific? There are several things that could mean that all have massive consequences for your question. Also when you say subsite root domain what does that mean? Try to avoid generic/abstract terms and focus instead on hard concrete examples, e.g. reference actual URLs even if it's just site1.com or one.example.com to avoid ambiguity/confusion

Comment: This is in the context of a WordPress Multisite where i want to use a TLD such as example.com as one of the subsite urls.

Comment: can you edit your question to add that information as well as the other things i mentioned and specific examples so that it's clear what you mean? Most people don't look at the comments! Don't assume that knowing `example.com` is one of the subsite URLs means that we'll know what the others are, it's very ambiguous and unclear right now and everything is implied or assumed. Assume we're 5 year olds and say things outright so the reader doesn't have to figure it out

Comment: Thanks Tom, i've now updated the question. Could you let me know if that makes more sense, please? :)

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't told Plesk to redirect the request to primarysite.com and so WP never sees the subsite domain? Setting an alias in plesk might mean something _very_ different to what you thought, WP is already able to handle requests from multiple domains, they just need routing to WordPress on the filesystem

Comment: In Plesk when you set up a alias domain, you are given two options; DNS, DNSSEC and DigitalOcean DNS. So in theory I haven't intentionally  told plesk to redirect to the primary site, but maybe setting up a domain alias isn't the way to do this despite what i've ready in all the various guides. I've also tried setting this up as it sown Plesk domain with the root inside the root folder of the primary domain with no success, along setting the roo tin its own top level folder.

Comment: maybe you need to ask in a Plesk community to rule that out, as long as the request is routed to WP with the right address WP should handle it just fine, but if it’s interfered with before that there could be issues and WP will never know. It’s also possible your root site is a.example.com and you’re having troubles setting your subside to example.com, emphasis on example.com being the same, but it should handle that too. This is all assuming there is no domain mapping plugin and they’re 2 separate sites on the same multisite, and you aren’t trying to serve the _same_ site from multiple URLs

Comment: Either way alias does not sound like what you want

Comment: Thanks Tom. Plesk support are looking into this, i'll post an answer once I have one.